# Postgres: store hashlib's blake digest python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am working on `python web app` having database as `postgres` using `docker`. I need to initialize default settings for the app, so I have created `query.sql` script that runs when I fire `docker-compose build` command.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
    id         int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    user_name  varchar(200),
    salt       bytea,
    user_pwd   bytea
);

-- Generate salt and password from script and paste here
INSERT INTO person (user_name, salt, user_pwd)
    VALUES ('some_admin_name', b'\xdc`\x15_9\n\x16u\x11...', b'CPd\xa3\x15\xf3...')
```

The script `person.py`, I am using `hashlib` module, from that I am using `blake`

```
    def generate_salt_and_password(self, *, password: str) -> tuple[bytes, bytes]:

        digest_size: int = 16

        salt: bytes = os.urandom(16)

        h = hashlib.blake2b(digest_size=digest_size, salt=salt)
        h.update(password.encode())

        pwd: bytes = h.digest()

        return salt, pwd
```

On running, I am getting an error as

```
ERROR:  "\" is not a valid binary digit
   VALUES ('some_admin_name', b'\xdc`\x15_9\n\x16u...
                              ^
```

What I am missing?